# Handling Numbers in neo4j (node & Label)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to dump some date to Neo4J. Some of my node names (in the chosen format for dumping) has numbers, which have to be exported as node-names.

I encounter the following error when the node name or label starts with a number.

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax

MERGE (1:User {name: "u1"})
```

Is this because, internally neo4j has a unique ID?. How do we circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are just the syntax rules Neo4j uses. Also keep in mind that the thing you are referring to as the node name (1, in your example) is actually a variable name, and only persists for the duration of the query (or until it leaves scope if not carried over in a WITH clause to the next part of the query).

From the developer documentation:

> Variable names are case sensitive, and can contain underscores and
>   alphanumeric characters (a-z, 0-9), but must always start with a
>   letter...The same rules apply to property names.

While I didn't see anything about label names, it looks like it follows the same syntax rules.

Property values, of course, can be anything you want.

You described the limitation as a "problem", so I'm guessing there's a perceived issue with this in your import, likely around the confusion between variables and what you called node names. If that's so, then please add some more details to your description, and I can add on to my answer accordingly.